# Sound not working on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 21.10

Here's the relevant information:

```
> inxi -SMA
System:    Host: 321go Kernel: 5.13.0-20-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 40.5 Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 82K1 v: IdeaPad Gaming 3 15IHU6 serial: <superuser required> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0Q55722 WIN serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: H4CN16WW(V1.01) 
           date: 03/24/2021 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 
           Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.13.0-20-generic running: yes 
           Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: yes 
           Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.32 running: yes
```

There are 3 sound servers. I have another system with Ubuntu installed there is only one sound server. Is the output of Audio section usual?

Here's the output of logs:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after upgrading to 21.10, what worked for me was:

1. to remove pulseaudio and alsa (`sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends pulseaudio alsa-base alsa-utils`);
2. to install pipewire-pulse (`sudo apt install pipewire-pulse`) and
3. reboot

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/qj7ai8/ubuntu_2110_with_pipewire_and_pulseaudio/
- https://www.mind-overflow.net/post/how-to-reset-pulseaudio-and-alsa-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Installing the `pipewire-pulse` package solved it on Ubuntu 21.10 impish:

```
sudo apt install pipewire-pulse -y
```