# After a few minutes of audio/video playback computer starts beeping - 21.10, Asus T100TA

Tags: sound, asus

Whenever I play audio from various apps, like Spotify, or any browser (I checked Firefox and Tor), the computer starts beeping after couple of minutes. The beeping stops only when I stop playback. I also checked if it appears when I plug in 3.5 mm jack headphones and it does. Before 21.10 I was using 20.04 LTS and there were no audio issues there. There is a similar question raised in regards to ASUS T102HA, but since I am a new user I am not allowed to add comments there. I wanted to run sudo sensors-detect according to what was suggested there, but the app started to ask me about loading various kernel modules, so at some point I just opened built in resources monitor. Please see the screenshot attached. CPU load was around 50% when the beeping started and it raised to 100% until I killed the process. My machine - ASUS T100TA

Comment: try https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374264/sound-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-10

Comment: What screen shot?

Comment: In case of a screenshot - apparently AskUbuntu didn't let me attach it, but overall it was just showing what I described above. CPU usage rises after beeping starts.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374264/sound-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-10 - I tried this solution, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same with my last upgrade. Downloading https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/archive/refs/heads/main.zip installing v1.9-rc1 seems to have fixed it for me. For whatever reason 1.9 leads to buzzing but rc1 doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to fix this issue under Ubuntu 21.10, so I wanted to see if the new LTS release fixes this bug, as I didn't have that problem on 20.04. Current LTS release actually completely destroyed sound output - none audio drivers were detected, reinstalling Alsa and Pulseaudio didn't make any effect. However that was good, because it directed me towards looking for missing audio drivers fix and I finally found this: [Heikomat Github](https://github.com/heikomat/linux/tree/cx2072x/cx2072x_fixes_and_manual?fbclid=IwAR1WwdwxDg5nokapBbWx8vTQEhXSz8dijtW_onLK-uBP48c8LDeqyJnL4po)

I ran the script `wget -qO- https://gist.github.com/heikomat/3fe272431b44b580c933bfb901a92257/raw | bash` and it completely fixed my audio settings. I am listening to like the third song in a row while typing this post and everything works pretty well. Heikomat, if you are here on Ask Ubuntu, then I am grateful for your great work and huge help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's github issue on this problem: https://github.com/thesofproject/sof/issues/3868.

To summarize, adding `options snd_sof sof_debug=1` to the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` should help.